# How to handle extra commas in csv file

Tags: java, android

I am creating a csv file in Android. At some places content contains commas how can I handle those commas.

Comment: Are you using some library to create the file? Escaping and quoting should be handled by that. If you're doing it all yourself, I recommend you read up on how CSV files work, this is really basic.

Comment: @Wooble No sir i am not using an library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSV format is defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

Values that contain commas must be enclosed within double quotes.

Double quotes within quoted values must be escaped by doubling them.

For example, here are two rows with three columns each.

```
hello, "me, you", "world"
"this is a ""quote""", "text", text
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify text qualifiers. Generally a double quote (") is used as text qualifiers. All the text is always put inside it and all the commas inside a text qualifier is ignored.

This is a standard method for all CSV, languages and all platforms for properly handling the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes. e.g. "1, Back Street",2,3,asdf,"dff,"

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape commas in strings which you want to write to the CSV file (if you use the comma as field separator). But seriously... don't write your own CSV writer/parser! Use a library for this. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes. e.g. "1, abc",2,3,asdf,"dff,"